# Limit model choices on foreign key Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following field

```
target_contenttype = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                       blank=True,
                                       null=True,
                                       related_name="target_object",
                                       on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                       limit_choices_to={'model__in':(
                                           ''        
                                       )})
```

On limit_choices_to i can't find the documentation on how to limit related model located on different app. Can someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `get_for_model()` (if you have imported the related models) or `get_by_natural_key()`, passing it the app name and the model name, both in lowercase:

```
from relatedapp.models import RelatedModel

limit_choices_to={'model__in':(
    ContentType.objects.get_for_model(RelatedModel),
    ContentType.objects.get_by_natural_key('relatedapp', 'relatedmodel'),
)}
```

Another way would be to create a Q object to filter on app label + model, both in lowercase:

```
limit_choices_to=(
    Q(app_label='app1', model='model1') | 
    Q(app_label='app2', model='model2')
)
```